# Observer to be called after shipment is saved

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento-2.2.5

I need to call observer which must be called when a shipment is created and **after it is saved**. I tried using the event

> sales_order_shipment_save_after

but it is called before shipment is saved and before there is an entry in the database.

Comment: which magento version are you on? there are differnces between 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3

Comment: version is 2.2.5

Comment: `sales_order_shipment_resource_save_after` should do the trick

Comment: nope its not working

Comment: then `sales_order_shipment_save_commit_after` probably does what you want. kudos to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120029/34273

Comment: not working at all or is everything called before there is an database entry?

Comment: everything is called before database entry

Comment: You can use a plugin for the corresponding resource model (the `afterSave` method)

Comment: `sales_order_shipment_save_commit_after` worked. @PhilippSander post it as an answer so I'll accept it.

Comment: @SufyanKhot awesome! I was glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sales_order_shipment_save_commit_after` does what you want.

The `*_save_commit_after` event is triggered after the transaction has been committed, i.e. when the changes were written to the database.

kudos to [Fabian Schmengler](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120029/34273)